# Flutter find width and height of PDF

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm converting a PDF into an image and to have the image showing in the exact dimensions as in the original PDF I need to know beforehand what are the dimensions of the PDF.

To download the PDF and convert into an image I do the following:

```
await Dio().download(urlFile, filePath).whenComplete(() async 
{
    File file = File(filePath);
    Uint8List bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
    
    final document = await PdfDocument.openData(bytes);
    final page = await document.getPage(1);
    final pageImage = await page.render(width: page.width, height: page.height, format: PdfPageFormat.JPEG);

    await page.close();
});
```

Original PDF dimensions: 457x1078

Output Image dimensions: 164x363

Unfortunately, both `page.width` and `page.height` assume wrong values, which leads to the converted image having wrong dimensions.

If I change my code into this:

```
final pageImage = await page.render(width: 457, height: 1078, format: PdfPageFormat.JPEG);
```

It works great, the image output has the correct dimensions. The PDF can have arbitrary dimensions, which means I cannot force absolute values.

How can I find the PDF dimensions width & height?

Comment: @KJ this PDF only has one page, it's a Receipt from a POS. I don't know any solution, I'll probably end up getting this information from my server.

Comment: @KJ the width is not fixed because customers can set the width manually, as well the margins, etc. This way the PDF size is always adapted to the customer printer size, which normally are 58mm, 70mm & 80mm.

I know which size the user sets the PDF to be printed in mm (for example 58mm) but how do I reach the number 457px?

Comment: @KJ yes, I know 164pt is the size of the PDF, but if I create the image with that dimension it comes all blurred (its like it's zooming in). I think I have found an hacky do solve this, I'll give more tries and if it works (at least its working with the 58mm dimension) I'll write here. thanks.

Comment: @KJ I must use JPEG since, at least this printer, won't print PNG, nor PDF.